# Pass data-attribute from DOM to function in AngularJS controller

Tags: dom, controller, angularjs, custom-data-attribute

I'm using AngularJs to change visibility of certain DOM elements. The visibility depends on what value was selected in a dropdownlist. More specifically, on a data-attribute of the selected `option` tag. I cannot populate the dropdown via AngularJs, because it's an existing ASP.NET control.

I thought about using `ng-change` and call a method on my controller but I'd have to pass an argument. This argument is in the DOM and not in my controller. Obviously, I'd like to keep it this way, and not access the DOM in my controller.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ttr6/1/), but this is my code:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="VehicleDetailsCtrl">
         <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="update()">
             <option value="1" data-carType="Car">Car 1</option>
             <option value="2" data-carType="Car">Car 2</option>
             <option value="3" data-carType="Truck">Truck</option>
        </select>
        <div ng-hide="isTruck">
            Hide if a truck was selected.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function VehicleDetailsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isTruck = false;
    $scope.selectedValue = null;
    $scope.update = function() {
        $scope.isTruck = !$scope.isTruck;
        // hide div here?
        // but then I'd need to know the selected option, 
        // but I don't want to reference the DOM here.
    };
}
```

Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Keep in mind that I cannot let AngularJs populate the `select` because ASP.NET already does that for me (and I can't change that at the moment).

Also, I need both the `selectedValue` (for post-back and saving it to the database) and the `data-carType` (for changing the DOM). I don't know at runtime what the id (or `value`) of the Truck `option` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a directive to create an object of vehicle types and watch the model value of the `select` to update your `isTruck` variable:

HTML:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedValue" check-is-truck>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('checkIsTruck', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.vehicleTypes = {};
        scope.selectedType = false;
        angular.forEach(element.find('option'), function(item, idx) {
            scope.vehicleTypes[item.value] = item.dataset.cartype; 
        });  
        scope.$watch('selectedValue', function() {
            scope.selectedType=scope.vehicleTypes[scope.selectedValue];
            scope.isTruck = scope.selectedType == 'Truck'
        })
    };
})

function VehicleDetailsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.isTruck = false;
    $scope.selectedValue = null;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7ttr6/2/

Comment: In the end, I went with KnockoutJs, but you're solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-change to update the value because ng-model takes care of that. And in ng-hide you need to simply compare the `selectedValue` with the value of 'Truck' option (int 3):

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue">
     <option value="1" data-carType="Car">Car 1</option>
     <option value="2" data-carType="Car">Car 2</option>
     <option value="3" data-carType="Truck">Truck</option>
</select>
<div ng-hide="selectedValue==3">
    Hide if a truck was selected.
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adibih/wSu6q/)

Comment: No can do. I edited my question to clarify, but at runtime, I don't know that Truck's value is 3.